# Pivot with prefixed column names in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Using Oracle 11g I wish to pivot the following table

```
ID  PREFIX  VALUE1  VALUE2
1   C01_    123     AAA
1   C02_    456     BBB
1   C03_    789     CCC
2   C01_    123     AAA
2   C02_    456     BBB
3   C01_    123     AAA
```

to

```
ID  C01_VALUE1  C01_VALUE2  C02_VALUE1  C02_VALUE2  C03_VALUE1  C03_VALUE3
1   123         AAA         456         BBB         789         CCC
2   123         AAA         456         BBB         null        null
3   123         AAA         null        null        null        null
```

In practice there are more than two value columns. In short, I would like to find a way to pivot the table prefixing column names using the prefix column.

Comment: No, unless you use XML pivoting

Answer (score 1):

The request seems a bit silly - you seem to care about the column NAMES, which can always be changed in the SELECT clause. If you want it more or less automated, then you can do something like this:

```
select *
from   your_table
pivot  ( max(value1) as value1, max(value2) as value2
         for prefix in ('C01_' as C01, 'C02_' as C02, 'C03_' as C03)
       )
;
```

When you pivot using the PIVOT clause, if you don't change the column names in SELECT, they will be the alias(es) in the IN clause, followed by underscore, followed by the alias(es) you give after the aggregate function(s) in PIVOT. The underscore is added automatically, so YOU shouldn't provide it in either alias.